# 'Draw' Identifier not found

Tags: c++

I have a problem with the following code:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL\glew.h>
#include <GL\freeglut.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "stdafx.h"
const int Width = 600;
const int Height = 600;
void display()
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    Draw();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void Draw() {
    glColor3f(0.7, 0.7, 0.7);
    glBegin(GL_LINES);
    const int Len = Width / 10;
    for (int i = 0; i <= Width - Len; i += Len)
    {
        glVertex2f(0, i);
        glVertex2f(Width, i);
        glVertex2f(i, 0);
        glVertex2f(i, Height);
    }
    glEnd();
}

void timer(int = 0)
{
    display();
    glutPostRedisplay();
    glutTimerFunc(10, timer, 0);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Initialize
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(Width, Height);
    glutInitWindowPosition(glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_WIDTH) / 2 - Width / 2, glutGet(GLUT_SCREEN_HEIGHT) / 2 - Height / 2);
    glutCreateWindow("Tetris");
    glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, Width, Height, 0, -1, 1);
    //Functions
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    //Timers
    timer();
    //Main Loop
    glutMainLoop();
}
```

After compilation I have one error: 
**Error C3861   'Draw': identifier not found.**
After some research [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev14.query?appId=Dev14IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(C3861)&rd=true) I am not sure how to solve this problem. As you can see there is declaration of this function.

Comment: Just specify a forward declaration before `void display()
{ .... }` : `void Draw();`

Comment: This has nothing to do with Windows or OpenGL. It is a very basic C++ question.

Comment: Declare them in the right order and you're fine.